# How can Get user_id Adder and user_id New Member? API Telegram

Tags: php-telegram-bot

when a user  **added** in group/channel `telegram` .

How can Get `user_id` Adder(person add member) and `user_id` New Member?

How Get the `username` of them?(it's possible)

Answer (score 2):

Only group support this, you won't receive message when channel added users.

You can try your self by add [@RawDataBot](https://t.me/RawDataBot) to group, and invite anyone. You will see `message.from.id` id inviter, and `message.new_chat_members.0.id` will be new member's ID. If their have [@username](https://t.me/username), you will have `xxx.username` field with `xxx.id`.